# Ubuntu goes to a black screen that says boot install

Tags: grub2

When trying to install Ubuntu it says

```
(initramfs)mounting /dev/loop0 on //filesystem.
squashfs faild 
Can not mount /dev/loop0 
(/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs)on //filesystem.
squashfs
```

then a command prompt appears like this

```
(Initramfs)_
```

What should I do to get it up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem: in my case it helped to change the disk-format the Ubuntu USB installation to Fat32 (I think it was NTFS before)